# Why are these two metrics equivalent?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I have to show that

$$ d'(x,y) := min ( d(x,y), 1 ) $$

defines an equivalent metric to $d$.

As far as I know, two metrics are considered equivalent if

$$ d(x_n, x) \to 0 \Leftrightarrow d'(x_n, x) \to 0$$
$$ \forall x_n \subseteq \Omega, \forall x \in \Omega$$

So my idea was

if $d(x_n, x) \to 0$ then $d'(x_n, x) = min(0, 1) = 0$ and

if $d'(x_n, x) \to 0$ implies $min(d(x_n, x), 1) = 0$ so $d(x_n, x) \to 0$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Almost, you don't have that $d'(x_n,x) = min(0,1)$ since it is possible that $d(x_n,x)$ is never zero, but you do have that $d'(x_n,x) = min(d(x_n,x),1)\leq d(x_n,x)$. You can then use this to show that $d'(x_n,x)\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: That are equivalent in the sense that they produce the same topology. In general, for any nonnegative monotone no de reason bounded function $F$ on $[0,\infty)$  such that $F(t)=0$ Iff $t=0$ and such that  $F(t+s)\leq F(t)+F(s)$ , we have that $\rho(x,y)=F(d(x,y)$ yields a metric equivalent to $d$